# Python3 impossible to pass @property as decorator argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I've implemented decorator that can receive extra arguments and want to use it with class methods. I want to pass @property as decorator argument, but instead of @property result I got this:

```
<property object at 0x7f50f5195230>
```

This is my decorator:

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        self.func = None
        self.some_arg = some_arg

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        import functools
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, instance)

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self._process_sync(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def _process_sync(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print(self.some_arg)
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
```

My test class:

```
class Test(object):
    @property
    def some_data(self):
        return {'key': 'value'}

    @Decorator(some_data)
    def some_method(self):
        print('method output')
        return None
```

Usage:

```
test = Test()
test.some_method()
```

Two questions:

1. How to correctly pass property to receive @property result instead of `<property object at 0x7f50f5195230>`
2. Does it possible to pass class properties/methods to the decorator if they are below in code?

Comment: It's a little tricky to understand what you expect the passed in property to do in your decorator. Do you expect to look up whatever value it's returning when the decorated method is called? Or do you want it to somehow lookup the decorator value up front, right when you pass it in? This isn't really relevant in your example, since the property always returns the same value, but one that is less predictable would be trickier.

Comment: @Blckknght I want to use the @property value in decorator. In the original example I want to pass some exceptions handlers to use them with decorated function. But for question I have created simple example to understand the mechanism how to correctly pass `@property` to get its result (I mean dict from the example above) instead of object

Comment: @Blckknght in the other words I have no idea how to use this `<property object at 0x7f50f5195230>` to receive dict from the property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `property` object is a descriptor. To get a value out of it, you need to call its `__get__` method with an appropriate instance. Figuring out when to do that in your current code is not easy, since your `Decorator` object has a bunch of different roles. It's both a decorator factory (getting initialized with an argument in the `@Decorator(x)` line), and the decorator itself (getting called with the function to be decorated). You've given it a `__get__` method, but I don't expect that to ever get used, since the instance of `Decorator` never gets assigned to a class variable (only the wrapper function that gets returned from `__call__`).

Anyway, here's a modified version where the `Decorator` handles almost all parts of the descriptor protocol itself:

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg      # this might be a descriptor, like a property or unbound method

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        return self         # we still want to be the descriptor in the class

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            arg = self.arg.__get__(instance, owner)   # try to bind the arg to the instance
        except AttributeError: # if it doesn't work, self.arg is not a descriptor, that's OK
            arg = self.arg

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):   # this is our version of a bound method object
            print(arg) # do something with the bound arg here
            return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
```